# Index with a Complex MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT venues.venue_name, count( distinct checkin.user_id ) AS total_count, category_id
    FROM checkin
    INNER JOIN venues ON checkin.internal_venue_id = venues.venue_primary_id
    WHERE checkin.item_id = '3783'
    and is_category_valid = 1 and created_at >= DATE_SUB('2013-07-07 12:35:06', INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    GROUP BY checkin.internal_venue_id
    ORDER BY total_count DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

I'm struggling with the index required for this query. Is the correct index:

```
checkin: (internal_venue_id, item_id, is_category_valid, created_at, user_id)
```

Or is there another query path that is more desirable?

Answer (score 0):

The index you suggest is relevant.

But there is no such thing as a "correct" or a "best" index per se, you need to take into account the full structure of your tables as well as the cardinalities. For example, how many records (in proportion) are there with `is_category_valid = 1`? If most records meet this condition, an index on this field would be of little use.

The underlying idea is to include columns in order of "importance", that is to say on the most discriminative columns first. For instance, I would push the column `is_category_valid` to the end of your index if most categories are "valid".

(there is an exception for columns appearing in the `GROUP BY` and the `ORDER BY` clauses, but you already know this, so it seems)

You should take a look at the query execution plan (`EXPLAIN SELECT [your query here]`) and see how the query is processed. Try various combinations and see which one performs better. Keep in mind that the "best" index today might become less optimal as your data set evolves.

Answer (score 0):

RandomSeed has very good points.  For what you are running into though, I would try to optimize an index on the smallest granularity of what you are asking for.  In this case, you are specifically looking for a given "item_ID".. move that into the front position of the index.  Then I would have other criteria or group by as next consideration... again, based on granularity of result expectations. You have the Is_Category_Valid and Created_At.. I would expect since most categories would be valid, I would have created_at in the second position.  This basically is stating the index can jump to Item ID 3783, and within that, go to the created date of 2013-07-07 (less 5 days via Date_sub).  At this point I would through in the group by criteria for the index and finally the Valid

```
index (item_id, created_at, interval_venue_id, is_category_valid )
```

But, every query is different, you do need to look at the fastest way to get the granular level of data... and having a covering index (when possible) that prevent the need to going to the raw page data level helps make it faster too.

Comment: So you would not include the user_id as part of the index?

Comment: @gregavola, sorry, put that at the end as it's just an "extra" you want as a column and no benefit of location for the where or group by / order by criteria in a query.

Comment: yes, but I am order by the count(distinct user_id) of that column. Should that range high?

Comment: @gregavola, if you are expecting a lot of different "user_id" value for a given venue, then I would have that column before the "is_category_valid" part of the index